# Which one I should use? Infinitive or present participle?

Tags: infinitives, present-tense, participles

Which sentence is grammatically correct?

1. *I think it is good for students to have cellphones.*
2. *I think having cellphones is good for students.*

Comment: Why do you not allow for the possibility that they're both grammatical? But I'd say 'having cellphone**s**' sounds clumsy (10 each?), so I'd always pick (1).

Comment: Yes, the assumption that there is only one correct way to say anything tends to make students unconfident. There are always thousands of ways to say anything. Both of the above sentences are grammatically correct, for instance. The second one is simpler and has fewer transformations than the first (there's no "dummy _it_" from Extraposition, for instance), but they're both complex sentences, with three clauses each, and a lot of syntax.

Comment: I prefer the second; but that doesn't matter. (I'd also normally drop the *I think*.) Others will prefer the first. They are both grammatical.